# Commenting erb files in Atom doesn't work well

Tags: ruby-on-rails, atom-editor, erb

Toggle comments in `.html.erb` files becomes from:

```
<%= link_to 'Back', bins_path %>
```

To

```
<%# <%= link_to 'Back', bins_path %> %>
```

a final extra `%>`.

I haven't found a way to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I just replace the `=` with `#` like

`<%# link_to 'Back', bins_path %>`

But that is done manually (not `Ctrl+/`)

Comment: You might need to search for an explicit `html.erb` language mode extension.